# condition in shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
output=`./process_test.sh status_pid | grep "NOT STARTED: process_1" --line-buffered`
if[[ -z  ${output} ]]
then
    echo "process is not running"
else
    echo "process is  running"
fi
```

where `./process_test.sh status_pid` is my utility for finding whether a process is running or not .e.g. if `process_1` is not running it will give: `NOT STARTED: process_1`. Further 
this utility is perfect and does not have any issue. I suspect the issue is with `if` syntax

on running this script I get the following output:

```
./test.sh: line 18: if[[ -z  NOT: command not found
./test.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./test.sh: line 19: `then'
```

Can you help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use spaces to separate keywords such as `if` from the arguments or commands such as `[[`.

```
#!/bin/sh
output=$(./process_test.sh status_pid | grep -e "NOT STARTED: process_1" --line-buffered)
if [[ -z ${output} ]]
then
    echo "process is not running"
else
    echo "process is running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like

```
if [[ -z ${output} ]]
then
    ...
```

So you had missed a .

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot cleaner to write this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! ./process_test.sh status_pid |
        grep "NOT STARTED: process_1" > /dev/null; then
    echo "process is not running"
else
    echo "process is  running"
fi
```

Note that the --line-buffering argument is irrelevant, since
the pipe is not going to finish until after all of the input
is read.  (Well, it's not totally irrelevant--it will make the
script run negligibly slower.)

Also note that '[[' is not standard.  According to the [shell language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), it
 "may be recognized as ( a ) reserved (word) on some implementations ..., causing unspecified results".  In other words, it is what is commonly known as a "bashism" (although it is valid in shells other than bash), and if you use it you must not use `#!/bin/sh` as your interpreter, but should specify `#!/bin/bash`.